# Facebook SDK detect user changed in Facebook Apps itself

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin.android

I would like to ask that is there any methods in Facebook SDK able to identify whether the user logged in in the Facebook Apps changed or not? Because I am using the AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken method to check whether user logged in before or not, but it won't update if user in Facebook Apps changed. Thanks!

Here is how I perform checking:

```
            // Get the current access token if user logged in before
            AccessToken objAccessToken = AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
            // Check the token value, access token validity and data access validity
            bool blnIsLoggedIn = objAccessToken != null && !objAccessToken.IsExpired && !objAccessToken.IsDataAccessExpired;

            if (blnIsLoggedIn)
            {
                // If user logged in, direct perform to get user profile
                GetFacebookUserProfile(objAccessToken, strUserProfileScopes);
            }
            else
            {
                // If user not logged in, perform login
                LoginManager.Instance.LogIn(CurrentActivity, DefaultScopes);
            }

            private void GetFacebookUserProfile(AccessToken objAccessToken, string strUserProfileScopes)
            {
                GraphRequest objGraphRequest = GraphRequest.NewMeRequest(objAccessToken, new clsGraphJSONObjectCallback());

                Bundle objParameters = new Bundle();
                objParameters.PutString("fields", strUserProfileScopes);
                objGraphRequest.Parameters = objParameters;
                objGraphRequest.ExecuteAsync();
            }
```

Comment: You shouldnt be able to track what's going on in another app on the phone. You can force logout based on a time out and that will force the user to login with Facebook again. So if the user logged in on the Facebook app changes, you will be able to "track" it

Comment: @Saamer Understood, thanks for your explanation!